# Powershell: Can't Get RegEx to work on multiple lines

Tags: regex, powershell

I am getting notes from a ticket that come in the form of:

```
[Employee ID]: 
[First Name]: Test
[Last Name]: User
[Middle Initial]: 
[Email]: 
[Phone]: 
[* Last 4 of SSN]: 1234
```

I've tried the following code to get the first name (in this example it would be 'Test':

```
    if ($incNotes -match '(^\[First Name\]:)(. * ?$)')
        {
            Write-Host $_.matches.groups[0].value
            Write-Host $_.matches.groups[1].value
        }
```

But I get nothing. Is there a way I can use just one long regex pattern to get the information I need? The information stays in the same format on every ticket that comes through.

How would I get the information after the [First Name]: and so on....

Comment: You could also match `(?m)(?<=^\[First Name]: +).+`, but I suspect it would be less efficient than @Wiktor's answer, as it employs a variable-length lookbehind. Note that there is no capture group, just the match. Depending on requirements you might change `.+` to `\S+`, `[A-Z][a-z]*$` or something else (if, for example, Billy-Bob Thornton were to submit a ticket). [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sEb2cb/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
if ($incNotes -match '(?m)^\[First Name]: *(\S+)') {
    Write-Host $matches[1] 
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rhDfkB/1). If you can have any kind of horizontal whitespace chars between `:` and the name, replace the space with `[\p{Zs}\t]`, or some kind of `[\s-[\r\n]]`.

*Details*:

- `(?m)` - a `RegexOptions.Multiline` option that makes `^` match start of any line position, and `$` match end of lines
- `^` - start of a line
- `\[First Name]:`  - a `[First Name]:` string
- `*`  - zero or more spaces
- `(\S+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more non-whitespace chars (replace with `\S.*` or `\S[^\n\r]*` to match any text till end of string).

Note that `-match` is a case insensitive regex matching operator, use `-cmatch` if you need a case sensitive behavior. Also, it only finds the first match and `$matches[1]` returns the Group 1 value.

Comment: Is there a way I can directly use the regex expression with the $incNotes variable so all I get is the first name? I’d be nice to not use the “if” statement, actually.

Comment: @Joe You still need to know if there is a match or not, right? Or are you sure there will always be a match? If so, just use `$incNotes -match '(?m)^\[First Name]: *(\S+)' | Out-Null` and then use `$matches[1]`.